# How do I add AngularJS Material to existing Drupal/Angular app correctly?

Tags: javascript

I've inherited a somewhat complicated application that injects form partials into a master page (all managed by Angular) on a Drupal site. We're using the AngularJS Drupal module, Drupal is 7.x Angular is 1.3.4.

Right now the .module has this:

```
drupal_add_library('angularjs', 'angularjs');
drupal_add_js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js', 'external');
```

This seems to work ok, all the scripts are loaded on the rendered page w/ jQuery first and then `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js?v=1.3.4"` and so on; including animate, aria, and messages. Lastly, material is loaded.

In app.js the module is declared and reused per [this error page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=ngMaterialProvider%20%3C-%20ngMaterial) looking something like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .service('myCoolService', function () { /* ... */ });

angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('myDirective', ['myCoolService', function (myCoolService) {
    // This directive definition does not throw unknown provider.
}]);
```

The module declaration looks like this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ngCookies", "ngMessages", "ngSanitize"]);
```

Aside from me adding material this all worked before I got to it so I'm reasonably confident this is correct. Once I add material:

```
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ngCookies", "ngMaterial", "ngMessages", "ngSanitize"]);
```

I get a bunch of unknown provider errors, looks like one for each item:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$jqLiteProvider <- $$jqLite <- $animateCss <- $$mdAnimate <- $mdUtil <- showDirective
```

Notice it seems to be looking for jqLite now instead of using jQuery. I don't think it's version, according to the material docs, all 1.x versions are supposed to work with Angular 1.x. I've tried putting `ngMaterial` in different spots in the order with no luck as well. I'm sure I'm messing up the service injection somehow but I'm not sure how.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#136-robofunky-danceblaster-2014-12-08 ...The `$$jqLite` service didn't exist until angular 1.3.5. You either need to update the version of angular, or use a version of material that's compatible with 1.3.4

Comment: This is what it's looking like. All docs I could find just say Material supports 1.3.x or whatever. Went back to 0.10.1 before it stopped breaking. At least its not something more obscure to fix, thanks.